# Conditional formatting in Excel combining TODAY and ISBLANK functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some help with conditional formatting in Excel. I'm trying to say "If the date in a cell (D10) is in the past & the cell below (D11) is blank THEN turn red".

I'm typing this `=AND (d10<TODAY() , ISBLANK (d11))` but having no joy.

Can anyone correct where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: does D11 have a formula that returns an empty string (`""`)

Comment: Try: `=AND (d10<TODAY() , LEN(d11)=0)`

Comment: `=AND(d10<today(),NOT(TRIM(d11)<>""))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=AND(D10<TODAY(), ISBLANK(D11)=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one @Lee ☺